# export domain names from httpd.conf

Tags: grep

i'm trying to export domain names from : "/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf" , domain names in file look like :

```
ServerName www.site.com
ServerName www2.site.org
```

i tried to use :

```
cat /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf | grep ServerName
```

but the output will contain :

```
# ServerName allows you to set a host name which is sent back to clients for
ServerName www.site.com
# to the server the response is coming from) it will use ServerName and
#    ServerName host.some_domain.com
# ServerName allows you to set a host name which is sent back to clients for
ServerName www2.site.org
# to the server the response is coming from) it will use ServerName and
#    ServerName host.some_domain.com
```

Comment: Instead of parsing `httpd.conf` it's probably better to parse the output of `/usr/local/sbin/httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`, because this finds also virtual hosts which are included in other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`grep '^ServerName' /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

This works because grep accepts [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in the pattern. `^` is the starting position of any line.

Also, do not use `cat` to pass files to things like `grep`, because `grep` has a filename parameter.

Comment: thanks from help .
now the output will look like :

   ' ServerName www.site.com
    ServerName www2.site.org '

can i , in someway make it :

    'www.site.com
    www2.site.org'

Comment: @user2676847 that is a whole another question that deserves another thread. But here is my solution: ``grep '^ServerName' /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf | cut -f 2- -d ' '``

Answer (score 0):

try awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0;print "Text at top";}/ServerName/ {count++;if(count == 1){print "Text  
between two ServerName", count}}END{print "Text at the end"}' /usr/local/apache
/conf/httpd.conf
```

replace text inside print statements with your own text.

BEGIN section will print: # ServerName allows you to set a host name which is sent back to clients for

END section will print: # to the server the response is coming from) it will use ServerName and #ServerName host.some_domain.com

and the print statement in between will print the statement between two ServerName entries.

Comment: This is the exact equivalent of the question. Not really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^ServerName' your_file
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print if(/^ServerName[\s]+www/)' your_file
```